# Should admin be a subdomain or a namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When would you use a subdomain over a namespace? i.e. http://admin.foo.com VS http://foo.com/admin

Alternatively, I also like how api.foo.com looks VS foo.com/api. I also find, subdomains a bit tricky to set up.

Comment: Personal preference. Makes no difference security and access wise.

Comment: @MattClark: subdomains are easier to work with. For example, you could point api.example.com to a different host by changing its A-record. And the root site keeps living where it lived.

Comment: Again goes back to personal preference. How I have my server setup, it is just as easy to setup a subdomain as it is to setup a folder inside an existing domain.

Comment: I would say it depends if these things all live inside the same application or not. Mounting another app inside a folder or a subdomain is no big deal with Web-Servers, but if your Rails app contains both the /admin and normal applications it gets trickier to serve one as a subdomain. Rails routing makes it easy to do the /admin thing.

Comment: @Tigraine good suggestion. Could you mention it as an answer

Comment: Did some more digging for the answer and it turns out you can do both.. thanks for the question .. didn't know the subdomain namespace option did indeed work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mounting another app inside a folder or a subdomain is no big deal with Web-Servers, but if your Rails app contains both the /admin and normal applications it gets trickier to serve one as a subdomain.

Thankfully the Rails router is very flexible in this regard and supports both scenarios rather well.

TLDR: Rails supports both ways through the routing engine and at this point it comes down to personal preference (although I suspect the subdomain option will not play too nicely with path helpers)

**/admin Routes**

To achieve the `/admin` routes, Rails supports the notion of namespaces in routing. So having a /admin area in the Rails app you just write this in your `routes.rb` like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
  resources :posts
end
```

You then put the controllers for the /admin area in controllers/admin/.rb and the class has to be prefixed with Admin (like `Admin::PostsController`).

Since most application's Admin area will most likely interact with the Models from the normal application it's probably safe to say doing namespacing is the most convenient way.

**Subdomain Routes**

But namespacing can also be used with subdomains as it turns out:

The Rails router can define `constraint` blocks and define the namespace inside these blocks.
So if you want to host the namespace from above only in the admin.example.com subdomain you can do this:

```
constraints(:subdomain => /admin/) do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :users
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

(I didn't know about the contraints feature but [this blog post](http://tabfugnic.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/rails-3-routes-namespace-subdomains/) seems to explain it quite well)

This obviously requires you to configure the web server in a way that it serves admin.example.com and www.example.com to the same Rails application.

I am not sure if session (achieved through cookies) is carried over but I guess you can figure this out.

Answer (score 5):

I think the other answer addressed the practicality issue, but purely from a security perspective:

Putting admin in a subdomain is recommended in the [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#additional-precautions) because it is more insulated from an XSS attack:

> Put the admin interface to a special sub-domain such as
>   admin.application.com and make it a separate application with its own
>   user management. This makes stealing an admin cookie from the usual
>   domain, www.application.com, impossible. This is because of the same
>   origin policy in your browser: An injected (XSS) script on
>   www.application.com may not read the cookie for admin.application.com
>   and vice-versa.

So from a security perspective, putting admin in a subdomain may be safer.